# Why can I not use the full capacity of my SSD?

Tags: windows-7, ssd, migration, paragon

I am using Paragon to migrate Windows 7 to an SSD.

The C drive which should be migrated is a 100GB partition.

During the process, Paragon formats the SSD to 80GB. Why doesn't it take the 100 GB? It later fails because it thinks there isn't enough space on the SSD. However the SSD is 11GB bigger than the partition, and only 45GB of the partition were used anyway.

How do I get around this? Is there another tool to do the same job which does it better ?

Answer (score 1):

Also "How-to Geek" has a very good post ([here](http://www.howtogeek.com/97242/how-to-migrate-windows-7-to-a-solid-state-drive/)).

Comment: Please put the information in your answer and add an attribution, or write your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](http://sonic-media.dk/?p=103) as very useful. You might want to read it. I hope it helps, im gonna do this too in about a week so let me know if it worked for you.

Comment: Please put the information in your answer and add an attribution.